# Dynamically updating data in the HTML, based on the date using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I am trying to make the year on a webpage update on the 1st of June (i need it on this day, because it is updating the year on my birthday). The question is: Is there a better way to do it with Vanilla JS because that way i am making a request every 24 hours to see if it is the expected date.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const informationYear = document.getElementById('information-heading-text-year');

    // update year function (check every day if its 1st of June and updates the year if true)
    function updateYear() {
        const birthdayDate = new Date(2013, 5, 1);
        let currDate = new Date();
                
        let years = 0;
        if(currDate.getMonth() === birthdayDate.getMonth() && currDate.getDay() == birthdayDate.getDay()) {
            years = currDate.getFullYear() - birthdayDate.getFullYear();
            informationYear.textContent = `${years}+`;
        }
    }

    // 1 day (86,400,000 milliseconds)
    const oneDayInterval = 1200;
    setInterval(updateYear, oneDayInterval);
});
```

What do you think will be the best solution for this problem? Is it even possible to do it without an API?

I am also open to solutions with database and a server

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean, but assuming you want to display the current age given a birthday in some element, this may be an idea. In the snippet the birthday is derived from a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the element. It's up to you to judge if this is actually *better* though.

```js
setAge(document.getElementById('information-heading-text-year'));

function setAge(ageElem) {
  const [now, birthday] = 
     [new Date(), new Date(...[ageElem.dataset.birthday.split(`,`)])];
  const [yBday, yNow] = 
     [birthday.getFullYear(), now.getFullYear()];
  const birthdayPassed = 
     new Date(yBday, birthday.getMonth(), birthday.getDate()) > birthday;
  const age = yNow - yBday - +(birthdayPassed);
  ageElem.textContent = `Current age for birth date ${
    birthday.toLocaleDateString()} is ${age}`;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="information-heading-text-year" data-birthday="2013,5,1"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking and asked myself, why checking for the exact date each day when i can just calculate the time until that date and set the timeout with that time. So i came up with this solution:

```
function updateEmployees() {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();
    const currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

    if(currentDate.getDay === 1) {
        informationEmployees.textContent = Number(informationEmployees.textContent) + 1;
    }

    if (currentDate.getDay === 15 && (currentDate.getMonth % 2 === 0)) {
        informationEmployees.textContent = Number(informationEmployees.textContent) - 1;
    }

    const nextUpdate = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1);
    if (currentDay === 1) {
        nextUpdate.setDate(15);
    } else if (currentDay >= 15) {
        if (currentMonth === 11) { // If it's December, wrap to January of the next year
            nextUpdate.setFullYear(currentYear + 1);
            nextUpdate.setMonth(0); 
        } else {
            nextUpdate.setMonth(currentMonth + 1);
        }
    }

    const timeUntilUpdate = nextUpdate - currentDate;
    
    if (timeUntilUpdate > 0) {
        setTimeout(updateEmployees, timeUntilUpdate);
    }
}
```

I will definitely try to play with the solution with data attribute you suggested tho.